# Nextcloud Box Performance

Tags: pi-3, networking, pi-2, nextcloud

As most of you probably know, nextcloud released the nextcloud box with support for RPI2 and with future softwareupdates RPI3.

My question is, has anyone bought the Nextcloud box? If you have, then what’s your experience with it? How is the performance of the HDD, especially read/write, because it’s connected via USB2 to the RPI2/3.

I’ve been looking for a cheap cloud solution for quite some time, but I haven't found any information about this setup, besides the usual marketing articles.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just set mine up for anyone else that comes across a build like this...
-Rpi3 connected with RJ45
-Samsung Evo plus SD card
-WD 1tb Pi Drive
-Ubuntu Snappy Core
-Asus 1200ac Wifi Router

I got about 100 MB/min write performance locally (from my computer to NextCloud), which to me is plenty for a low cost cloud that I have complete control over.

Answer (score 1):

I've bought one; received it 10/24/16. Unfortunately, I cannot log in through the web interface as the system instantly closes the connection after I enter my userID/password combo and click to enter or press an enter key. I can log in via SSH with Putty, but that's not exactly how I'd like to do things. Haven't had time to find the cause of this issue, and the guidance at https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/wiki isn't helpful.